# How to post to social media automatically? Android

Tags: android, facebook, twitter

In my application I want to allow posting to social media (lets use Twitter as example) using voice command. The conflict I am running into is that starting an intent for ACTION_SEND still requires the user to press the "tweet" button to ultimately post the message. Is there any way to post to twitter without that final step?

Lets do a simple example for making a post to Twitter via the app.

```
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setType("text/plain"); //application/twitter
                    intent.setPackage("com.twitter.android");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Test; please ignore");
                    SocialMediaActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

The above code will open the twitter application, the text "Test; please ignore" will be the message in the tweet. But the end user has to press the tweet button in the top right corner to finish the action. How to just post to twitter and then return back to the app?

Comment: You might have to integrate this into your app, but in any case the user will have to sign in and confirm the tweet

Comment: I see. I guess that makes sense. Thank you for your response!

Comment: No problem, I was looking into something similar the other day as well

Answer (score 0):

Use Twitter API. You can find info how to use it on the official site: [Docs](https://dev.twitter.com/)